# Error in `purrr::map_dbl()` caused by error in `quantile.default()`: ! missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling, missing-data

I got the following error message:

```r
`Error in **purrr::map_dbl()**:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: t1.
Caused by error in **quantile.default()**:
! missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE`
```

I tried to analyse circumplex data (library: circumplex) using this code:

```r
res.a1 <- ssm_analyze(.data = df.area1, 
    scales = c(a.pos1, v.neg1, a.neg1, v.pos1),                          
    angles = c(90, 180, 270, 360), measures = c(safe1, inter1), 
    measures_labels = c('Safety', 'Interaction')) 
summary(res.a1)`
```

This is the backtrace:

```r
Backtrace:
▆

 1. ├─circumplex::ssm_analyze(...)
 2. │ └─circumplex:::ssm_analyze_corrs(...)
 3. │   └─circumplex:::ssm_bootstrap(...)
 4. │     └─... %\>% dplyr::select(-fit_lci)
 5. ├─dplyr::select(., -fit_lci)
 6. ├─circumplex (local) reshape_params(., suffix = "lci")
 7. │ └─... %\>% tibble::as_tibble(nrow = nrow(.))
 8. ├─tibble::as_tibble(., nrow = nrow(.))
 9. ├─base::`colnames<-`(...)
10. │ └─base::is.data.frame(x)
11. ├─base::matrix(., ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
12. └─purrr::map_dbl(., .f = quantile, probs = ((1 - interval)/2))
13. └─purrr:::map\_("double", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
14.     ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
15.     │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
16.     ├─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
17.     ├─stats (local) .f(.x[[i]], ...)
18.     └─stats:::quantile.default(.x[[i]], ...)
19.       └─base::stop("missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE")

Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 4 hidden frames.
```

I don't know what are the missing values since all the variables have the observation count of 94.

Dataframe sample:

```r
id  v.neg1           v.pos1           a.neg1    a.pos1       inter1   safe1

1   -0.1031421  -1.7056656  -1.6342515  -0.2935107  6   5

2   -0.1031421  -0.7625329  0.9694712   -0.2935107  5   7

3   -0.1031421  0.1805999   0.3185405   -0.2935107  7   8

4   9.5922176   1.1237326   0.3185405   -0.2935107  3   8

5   -0.1031421  0.1805999   0.3185405   -0.2935107  5   8

6   -0.1031421  1.1237326   0.9694712   -0.2935107  8   8

7   -0.1031421  -0.7625329  -1.6342515  -0.2935107  5   5

8   -0.1031421  -1.7056656  -1.6342515  -0.2935107  4   5

9   -0.1031421  0.1805999   -1.6342515  -0.2935107  6   7

10  -0.1031421  2.0668654   0.9694712   -0.2935107  9   9
```

How can I resolve this error? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to find the missing values: `library(dplyr); filter(df.area1, if_any(everything(), is.na))`

Comment: that there aren't any missing values in your dataset.